# Common validation regex formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several models (18 models) that use the same format: { with: // } validations.  Is there a way to place all these common formats into one file or a way to use a constant so that if we make a change to the format it changes them to all the models without us having to update 18 different models without using sub-classing (models are already subclassed for other reasons)?

Example:

```
validates :some_value, allow_blank: true, length: { in: 10..50 }, format: { with: /\A^[a-fA-F0-9]*\Z/ }
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
# Some file, etc. that is accessible by all models
CONSTANT_FORMAT = /\A^[a-fA-F0-9]*\Z/

# Validation in several models (same validation)
validates :some_value, allow_blank: true, length: { in: 10..50 }, format: { with: CONSTANT_FORMAT }
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a module under `lib` folder and move all your common constants there

```
module CommonConstant
  CONST_REGEX = /\A^[a-fA-F0-9]*\Z/
end
```

And access the constant in your model like

```
validates :some_value, allow_blank: true, length: { in: 10..50 }, format: { with: CommonConstant::CONST_REGEX }
```

The module is in `lib` so the file will already be loaded if you have `lib` under `auto load path`